# Help Center article on question rate limiting should appear under Asking

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center, rate-limiting, question-restrictions

**Asking** is one of the more visible categories of Help Center, placed in upper left.

Among others, it contains the article on  *Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?* (blue circle below).

But the article *Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?* (red circle) is classified under *My Account* instead, even though it is specifically about asking questions.

I propose to move it to Asking, just above *Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?* -- the idea being that users encounter question rate-limiting earlier and more often than they encounter question blocks.

---

And while we are looking at that page... the screenshot is from SO, no matter what the site. Please make the page moderator-editable so that it can be customized. The advice on asking good questions has a better chance of helping when it's specific to the site.

---

[image: help center]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds reasonable to me:

[image: Done]